# Check-password insecure issue in ccs-pykerberos library

Tags: python, security, kerberos, change-password, cve

Is there any workaround for fixing the following issue or any alternative to the `kerberos` library?

> The python-kerberos `checkPassword()` method is badly insecure. It does a `kinit` (AS-REQ) to ask a KDC for a TGT for the given user principal, and interprets the success or failure of that as indicating whether the password is correct:

- Security issue: [checkPassword is insecure](https://github.com/apple/ccs-pykerberos/issues/31)
- Link to CVE entry about this security issue: [cve](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2015-3206)

There is no active response from the maintainers.

Comment: Do you actually need to use that function?  The "workaround" is not to use it.

Comment: So, we are not actually using the function as such, but we are using the library. When we scan the project, we get the cve there and that's why we want to get ride of it.

Answer (score 0):

> So, we are not actually using the function as such, but we are using the library. When we scan the project, we get the cve there and that's why we want to get ride of it

Then that's a good opportunity to get rid of the pykerberos library completely and port the application to something more modern, namely the python-gssapi or pyspnego modules.

Merely having the checkPassword function is harmless as long as you don't use it, but of course all of it really indicates that the ccs-pykerberos library as a whole is unmaintained and could be replaced.

- If you only need Kerberos-via-SPNEGO, use [pyspnego](https://pypi.org/project/pyspnego/) which is cross-platform (it uses either sspilib or python-gssapi underneath).
- For more specific Kerberos tasks (e.g. non-SPNEGO-based protocols), [python-gssapi](https://pypi.org/project/python-gssapi/) is the modern alternative if you want UNIX GSS-API, while [sspilib](https://pypi.org/project/sspilib/) is the equivalent for Windows SSPI.

All of them have a different interface so it's not a straightforward replacement, but generally more pleasant to use. (Whereas pykerberos is basically a clone of the Objective-C API from macOS.)

```py
ctx = spnego.client(hostname="foo.example.com",
                    service="HTTP",
                    protocol="negotiate")
token = ctx.step()
```

The last option is to vendor your own copy of ccs-pykerberos and just delete the offending function – it's not like pykerberos is going to change much at this point. (After all, pykerberos is just bindings to libkrb5, and all the security-sensitive code lives in the external libkrb5 library.)